# Slicer for a measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How to add a slicer with measure as a field. If not possible, what is the work around for that?

I have a table with data as follows:

```
City         Name         Count
x             a             5
y             b             7
x             c             6
```

I want to have a table as follows with a slicer if total population of a city is greater than 10 or not.

```
City       Total population
x           11
y           7
```

Here total population is a measure

Answer (score 1):

Add following calculated columns:

```
cityPopulation = 
var temp = Table1[city]
return calculate(sum(Table1[count]),ALL(Table1),Table1[city]=temp)

bigCity = Table1[cityPopulation] > 10
```

Results in

```
city,cityPopulation,count,name,bigCity
x,   11,            5,    a,   true
x,   11,            6,    c,   true
y,   7,             7,    b,   false
```

Then use `bigCity` in a slicer.